# How to retrieve titles and prices from web page using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am working on a web scraping task using `R` and `rvest`.

I am trying to get the names of smartphones as well as their prices from a store web page.

I am using next code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
#Code
first_page <- read_html('https://catalogo.claro.com.ec/postpago/catalogo?utm_source=catalogo&utm_medium=menu-header&utm_campaign=equipos-celulares&utm_content=navigation')
links <- first_page %>% html_nodes(xpath="//*[@id='catalogo--productos']/div/div/section/article[1]/div/h3") %>%
  html_text()
```

When I tried previous code I got empty `character(0)` for `links`.

I have checked the source code from web page:

[image]

And set the xpath according to it but it is not working. Is there any way to get the titles and price for each smartphone using `rvest`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt with {rvest}:

```r
url <- "https://catalogo.claro.com.ec/postpago/catalogo?utm_source=catalogo&utm_medium=menu-header&utm_campaign=equipos-celulares&utm_content=navigation"

ses <- rvest::read_html_live(url)

ses$view() 

phones <- ses |>
  rvest::html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="catalogo--productos"]/div/div/section') |>
  rvest::html_elements("h3") |>
  rvest::html_text()
  
prices <- ses |>
  rvest::html_elements(".price-new") |>
  rvest::html_text()

cbind(phones, prices)
#>       phones                                                                                           
#>  [1,] "MOTOROLA EDGE NEO 40 (256GB)"                                                                   
#>  [2,] "SAMSUNG GALAXY S24 ULTRA (512GB) + BUDS 2"                                                      
#>  [3,] "SAMSUNG GALAXY S24 PLUS (512GB) + BUDS 2"                                                       
#>  [4,] "SAMSUNG GALAXY S24 (256GB) + BUDS 2 ONYX + TRAVEL ADAPTER 25W"                                  
[...]
#> [73,] "IPHONE 11 (64GB)"                                                                               
#>       prices     
#>  [1,] "$ 453,60" 
#>  [2,] "$ 1868,44"
#>  [3,] "$ 1286,88"
#>  [4,] "$ 1062,88"
[...]
#> [73,] "$ 588,00"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>